# Sending text to textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea that I would like to send a value to and I am using the following to achieve this..

```
<textarea style="width: 300px; height: 150px;" name="message"></textarea>

<a href="#updates" onclick="document.sendform.message.value='7'; return true;"style="color:white">Year 7</a>
```

This is working as expected however it also overwrites any text that is in the textarea already, is there any way I can achieve this without over writing the existing text in the textarea?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<a href="#updates" onclick="document.sendform.message.value += '7'; return true;"style="color:white">Year 7</a>
```

Change is `+=` instead of `+`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cSnUZ/1/)**

Comment: @Leoric80: Welcome :-). If the answer is helpful for you, you may, upvote or `accept` or do both :-)

Comment: @Al-Mothafar: ha.. ha.. i didn't realized it & didn't interpreted his comment in that way. Either way its cool & you are a funny guy :-)